# Relational schema using MySQL

Tags: mysql, relational-database, entity-relationship

I’m working on a system where the goal is to create a massive database to store keywords (I do have a **scraper** to get those keywords).

I use partitions to speed up the queries, this is my initial structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` char(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `currency` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`keyword`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(keyword)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('a') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('b') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 ...
 PARTITION p25 VALUES LESS THAN ('z') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p26 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Now, a new requirement was requested, besides of storing the keywords I need a way to create a relationship between the keywords.

Let's say that I have a seed keyword and relative keywords

Example:

**Seed keyword:** `Car`

**Relative keywords:** `Blue Car`, `Red Car`, `Convertible Car`, `2 doors`, `4 doors`

In another interaction,

**Seed keyword:** `Convertible Cars`

**Relative keywords:** `Ferrari`, `Mustang`, `2 doors`,

Then when a user searches for the keywords `Car` I'll need to show the related keywords up to 2 deep levels.

```
-Car
-- Blue Car
-- Red Car
-- Convertible Car
---- Ferrari
---- Mustang
```

`Keywords` table

```
+----+---------------+
| id | keyword       |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Car
|  2 | Blue Car
|  3 | Convertible Car
|  4 | Ferrari
|  5 | Mustang
|  6 | Red Car
+----+---------------+
```

I was thinking to use a `Proxy` table to store the relationship between the keywords

`Relationship` table

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | seed_id | related_id |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | 1        | 3
|  2 | 3        | 4
|  3 | 3        | 5
|  4 | 3        | 6
|  5 | 1        | 2
+----+----------+-----------+
```

And finally, use LEFT/JOINS to create the proper query.

**What do you think about this approach, given that the keywords table will have maybe hundreds of millions of rows?**

Another idea is just keep the keywords table and add a parent_id field but, in this case, I will have duplicate keywords and my priority is to have a row per keyword in order not to get a hipper-massive table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, how many relations can one keyword have? If it is something close to parent-children relationship, which means one item has only one parent, but can have many children, then it is better to use a structure like that:

`+----+---------------------+-------------+
| id | keyword             | parent_id   |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Car                 |   0         |
|  2 | Blue Car            |   1         |
|  3 | Convertible Car     |   1         |
|  6 | Red Car             |   1         |
|  6 | Mustang             |   3         |
|  6 | Ferrari             |   3         |
+----+---------------------+-------------+`

Simple left join same table will help you then.

Comment: I think many, in the example `Car` can be a `parent` and a `child` from another seed keyword. Also `Blue Car` can be child from `Car` and `Ferrari`